# jsp submit form without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jsp

I have the following javascript code in my jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ibutton').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();


            $.ajax({
                url: "search",
                type: "post",
                data: value,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#message").html(data).slideDown('slow');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and also the following form:

```
<form action="search" name="sub" id="sub">
    <input name="search" type="text">
      <input type="button" id="ibutton" value="Saveme"/>
</form>
```

And this is my servlet:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String search(HttpServletRequest req, @RequestParam String search){
    req.setAttribute("result", search);
    System.out.println("entered");
    return "search";
}
```

When I click the button "Saveme" the page does not redirect, but I expect to see "entered" written in the console, but I dont, why is this?

I used the following page as reference:
http://www.java4s.com/jquery-tutorials/submit-form-without-refreshing-page-in-javajsp-with-jquery/

Comment: "I expect to see "entered" written in the console" — Which console? The browser console? Or do you have a server side console?

Comment: `src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.js"`  — That's a *really* old version of jQuery. You shouldn't use it for new development.

Comment: If you replace the button with a submit button and remove the JavaScript, do you get the result you expect?

Comment: yes in the console , which one should I use, will using an old version affect things?

Comment: yes if i replace it with submit button and no javascript then I do see "entered" in the console

Comment: "yes in the console" — **Which one**? I suggested two possible ones.

Comment: no the console in eclipse.

Comment: "which one should I use" — In general, the latest stable version from the jQuery website. "will using an old version affect things" — Possibly. Features are deprecated, browser bugs are worked around.

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the browser console. Are there any errors? Open the Net tab. Compare the HTTP request made when you use a regular submit button to the one made when you use JavaScript. Do both go to the same URL? Do both get the response you expect?